# screen list presettings

Tags: gnu-screen

Commonly I'm working with a single screen with many windowlist in it.

ex:

```
$ screen -r work
```

`[ctrl]+[A] , ["]`

```
Num Name                                                                                                                                                                          Flags

   0 root                                                                                                                                                                              $
   1 bash                                                                                                                                                                              $
   2 bash                                                                                                                                                                              $
   3 alpha                                                                                                                                                                             $
   4 alpha                                                                                                                                                                             $
   5 samsung root                                                                                                                                                                      $
   6 samsung                                                                                                                                                                           $
   7 sshdj                                                                                                                                                                             $
   8 light                                                                                                                                                                             $
   9 dev01                                                                                                                                                                             $
  10 bash                                                                                                                                                                              $
  11 ...
```

*Problem**

Host reboot forces me to bind windowlist again manually.

Is there any workaround to bind windows list and window names for screen session automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to recreate all the windows you can put in your `~/.screenrc` lines with the name, number and command, eg:

```
screen -t root  0 bash
screen -t bash  1 bash
screen -t alpha 3 bash
```

or you can run from the command line the equivalent commands eg:

```
$ screen -S work -X screen -t samsung 6 bash
```

If you want to name or rename existing windows you can do so with eg:

```
$ screen -S work -p 5 -X title 'samsung root'
```

Comment: It works!) I've create **work_prepare** script with all commands and names I need. Thank you a lot.